# Bootstrap dropdown not working with shadow root

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, frontend, web-component

I was trying to create a navbar component in a .js file so I can use it on multiple pages(not allowed to use react or other libraries for this project). I copied the navbar from bootstrap and pasted it in my navBar.js.
The CSS style worked fine but when I clicked the button the dropdown menu didn't show up.

Could anyone tell me what's the problem and how can I solve it?

another question, I saw some online comments say don't use web components. Should I keep on using it or just pasted the navbar into my index.html(in where the dropdown button works fine)

Here is my navBar.js:

```
const navTemplate = document.createElement('template');
navTemplate.innerHTML = 
    `
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="d-flex">
              <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    `;
class NavBar extends HTMLElement{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.attachShadow({mode:'open'});
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(navTemplate.content);
        
    }
    connectedCallback(){
    }
     
}

window.customElements.define('nav-bar', NavBar);
```

And this is my index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">


    
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    
    
    <nav-bar></nav-bar>
    
    <script src='../components/navBar.js'></script>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-SR1sx49pcuLnqZUnnPwx6FCym0wLsk5JZuNx2bPPENzswTNFaQU1RDvt3wT4gWFG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-j0CNLUeiqtyaRmlzUHCPZ+Gy5fQu0dQ6eZ/xAww941Ai1SxSY+0EQqNXNE6DZiVc" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, Wenze, I have the same issue, if you find solution, please comment! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that the dropdowns aren't initialized correctly. You could do that yourself with `new bootstrap.Dropdown(dropdownToggleEl)` in `connectedCallback`,
but that leaves you with work for opening, closing and triggering events on clicks and such. The "culprit" is Shadow DOM.

This is one of those cases where we would suggest to **not use Shadow DOM**. You are just wraping the layout into a component and even importing the CSS. Unless there is a reason to use Shadow DOM (like custom CSS encapsulation), skip it. It's fine to have components without Shadow DOM alongside others that do.

Or you could **alternatively use slots**. Replace the `li` tags in your components template

```
...
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <slot></slot>
    </ul>
    ...
</div>
...
```

and declare them with the markup of your component in the index.html:

```
<nav-bar>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
  </li>
</nav-bar>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by adding below to carousel.css, Shadow DOM works now!

`.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {display: block;}`

Comment: but it's still not working on iPhone browsers, I can use Shadow DOM for Footer only! Anyone that knows how to, please comment!